# how can we add recoil to spectating mode?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Recoil is removed in spec. mode. But in some big organization (e.g. Techlabs at yesterday) they stream from source with actual recoil ingame. But normally when you spectate or watch a demo there is no recoil at all. so I belive there is a command for this.

Answer (score 1):

RCON sv_recoil 1

Look here, http://www.nitroserv.com/fr/forum/topic/csgo-les-plugins/37526/csgo-cvar-and-command-list/

Many others are also having this problem, just like you my friend.
http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3090557

I do not belive theres a command for this though, VALVE will probably fix this in the future i asume.

Comment: Can you clarify your answer, please? You provide a command to modify one of the server variables but this doesn't affect spectator mode, as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

If Spectators have no Recoil, this command has been Set up in the configuration file:

**sv_specnoclip "1"**

Set **sv_specnoclip "0"** to make the Recoil visible in Spectating-Mode.